# How to destroy resource in driver module when SIGKILL signal?

Tags: linux, resources, signals, kill

I know some user space resources (e.g. fd/socket) used by a process will be destroyed automatically by kernel when "kill -9". But I am still confused about how driver (in kernel space) resource destroyed in this situation? Let me show an example below:

1. Driver code implemented like this:

```c
static void *mm;
static long my_ioctl(unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg, void *priv)
{
    switch (cmd) {
    case IOC_CREATE_RESOURCE:
        mm = kmalloc();
        break;
    case IOC_DESTROY_RESOURCE:
        kfree(mm);
        break;
    }

    // ...
}

static struct file_operations myfops = { 
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = my_open,
    .unlocked_ioctl = my_ioctl,
};
```

2. A user process started like this:

```c
fd = open();
ioctl(fd, IOC_CREATE_RESOURCE);
// do somethings with the resource
ioctl(fd, IOC_DESTROY_RESOURCE);
close(fd);
```

3. However, just before the second `ioctl`, the process is killed with "kill -9" command. That mean the second `ioctl` will ever get chance to be executed as far as know.

Does it mean the recourse created by the first `ioctl` is leaked? And how to fix it? The driver doesn't know anything about `kill -9` operation from my understanding.

Comment: Destroy allocated resources also in `release()` operation. File descriptor is always closed when process is terminated.

Comment: Thanks @dimich. In my case, more than one processes may open/close the same device fie, so the open/close operation may actually do nothing with resource allocation/destroy. Instead, `ioctl` is the actual resource manager.

Comment: Such apporach doesn't correspond to Linux device drivers philosophy. Resources should be associated with `private_data` of `struct file *file` parameter in operation handler. All resources created by ioctl() handler for specific `struct file *` must be destroyed in release() handler unless they are already destroyed before. Otherwise there will be resource leakage. UPD: for shared resources use reference counter (e.g. kobj) and destroy it when last process releases handler.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks @dimich. Seems to be a design issue which leads to current problem :(